# How to convert char that represents hex value to DWORD?

Tags: c, dword

I have a method `WriteValue` that writes a `DWORD` value to the registry:

```
const char *WriteValue(char* searchHandleId)
{
 //...
 DWORD value =  atoi(searchHandleId); // wrong!!!
 LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(
                                  hkey,
                                 "hwnd_to_track",
                                  0,
                                  REG_DWORD,
                                  (const BYTE*)&value,
                                   sizeof(value)
                                   );
 //..
}
```

The problem is that `searchHandleId` represents a hexadecimal number:

```
 printf( "Found .... hWnd: (%s)\n", searchHandleId);
```

Output: `Found .... hWnd: (002F1CE0)`

How to convert `searchHandleId` to `value` (DWORD value, in my case)?

Comment: interesting what is my problem in my question, someone down voted me for nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DWORD value = strtoul(searchHandleId, NULL, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sscanf(searchHandleId, "%x", &value);
```

may help you.

Comment: @MaximShoustin: `strtol` is a far superior solution, since it gives you precise error handling (unparsable text, overflow, etc.).